# R Shiny: How to defer loading Javascript files?

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny

I'd like to defer loading custom javascript in my Shiny application for faster startup, using the `defer` attribute in the script HTML tag.
I've tried to do the following:

`tags$script(src = "myscript.js", defer = T)`

which renders to: `<script src="myscript.js" defer="TRUE"></script>`

What can I use to just include "defer" as an attribute, without the "=TRUE" part? I've tried using NULL, but then it just doesn't appear. Does the "=TRUE" make a difference, or will it still behave appropriately?
Finally, and most relevant, will "defer" even work in the scope of a Shiny app?

Comment: `defer = ""` does the job

Comment: I've found [this section in the book Outstanding UI with Shiny](https://unleash-shiny.rinterface.com/htmltools-overview), specifically part 2.1. The appropriate way to include empty attributes is like `defer = NA`.